# JavaFx want to simulate key press when a button is pressed

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx

I am trying to simulate a CTRL+Z key press to activate the undo functionality of the TextField when I click the undo button in my JavaFX program. Any idea on if this is possible?

I tried creating a KeyEvent with the Key_Pressed and correct parameters then calling Event.fireEvent, but no changes occurred

Comment: Why not just call [`undo()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#undo()) on the `TextField` inside the button's on-action handler?

Comment: Sorry I meant HTMLEditor*

Comment: If you want your program to be cross-platform, remember that Macs don’t use Ctrl-Z for undo, they use ⌘-Z, which I believe is Meta-Z in Java.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75679525/javafx-want-to-simulate-key-press-when-a-button-is-pressed#comment133512221_75679525) you said you're using an `HTMLEditor`, not a `TextField`. If you *were* using a `TextField`, then simply calling `undo()` on it would work.

Looking at the source of `HTMLEditor` and its associated skin and behavior classes, it appears it doesn't directly handle the "undo command". Instead, this seems to be a feature of `WebView`. With that in mind, the following appears to do what you want:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static KeyEvent createUndoKeyEvent() {
        // On Windows, the "undo" shortcut is typically Ctrl+Z
        return new KeyEvent(
                KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                Character.toString(0),  // character (this is what Ctrl+Z gives me on my Windows device)
                "z",                    // text ( this is what Ctrl+Z gives me on my Windows device)
                KeyCode.Z,
                false, // shiftDown
                true,  // controlDown
                false, // altDown
                false  // metaDown
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var editor = new HTMLEditor();

        var undoBtn = new Button("Undo");
        undoBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            e.consume();

            // Grab the WebView used by the default HTMLEditor skin. Note it's
            // important this code is executed **after** the HTMLEditor has had
            // its skin set (which typically means after it's been displayed).
            var node = editor.lookup(".web-view");
            node.fireEvent(createUndoKeyEvent());
        });

        var top = new HBox(undoBtn);
        top.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        var root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(top);
        root.setCenter(editor);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Though I will note that the `HTMLEditor` / `WebView` does not seem to keep a very long history. In fact, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it only ever seems to undo one "action" (i.e., if I type some text, wait a while, then type more text, executing the "undo command" only ever gets rid of the "more text" bit no matter how many more times I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).